# String gets mangled when passed from Grunt to CasperJS

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, gruntjs, casperjs, cloud-init

I have a Gruntfile that can be executed from the command line with a string in Thai.

> grunt --data=นี่คือการทดสอบ

When I echo the string, I can see, that the string is intact:

> นี่คือการทดสอบ

I then spawn a CasperJS script with the string

```
grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd: '/usr/local/bin/casperjs',
    args: [
        '--engine=slimerjs',
        '--ssl-protocol=any',
        '--text=' + str,
        'test.js'
    ],
},
function(error, result, code)
{
    grunt.log.writeln(error + ' | ' + result + ' | ' + code);
    done();
});
```

But echoing it now gives me a mess:

> à¸<99>à¸µà¹<88>à¸<84>à¸·à¸­à¸<81>à¸²à¸£à¸<97>à¸<94>à¸ªà¸­à¸<9a>

The plot thickens: I'm running this all from cloud-init via userdata on an AWS instance.
However, when I run the same Grunt command via the shell, the scripts work fine. - Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use "this_is_a_test" instead of "นี่คือการทดสอบ". Maybe, this is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.

The bytes encoding changed coming into Casper from Grunt.

Ran them through `utf8to16` from http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/amuse/javascript/expert/utf.txt

All good to go.